# Accessing ClientID set by Google Analytics through Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, clientid, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have setup a new **Universal Analytics tracking** and would **like to store ClientID in one of the custom dimensions slots**.

The tracking tags are implemented through Google Tag Manager (using the predefined UA tag) and I am having the difficulty to passing the Client ID (via custom JavaScript Macro) with the basic pageview request.

I have named my tracker so that I can access it and this code runs without any error in console, however when used with GTM, it's returning an error.

```
ga.getByName('trackerGTM').get('clientId'))
```

produces an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you're firing the pageview `{{url}} matches RegEx .*`, correct? Could be that Universal hasn't loaded yet. Have you tried `{{event}} equals gtm.dom`? I haven't tested this, but it's a thought.

EDIT:

This looks like a bug. I was able to run:

```
function(){
  var client = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');
  return client;

}
```

And have it spit out the client ID with no problem.

Comment: Blexy, have you used custom JS macro for this? I did exactly the same thing and am still getting undefined.

Comment: Yeah, custom JS macro. However I did it with an unnamed tracker. I think there is a bug with trying to getByName using GTM.  Is it possible to have unnamed tracker?

Comment: Blexy, I am still getting undefined, but I think this might be related to unconventional GTM implementation in general (not directly in source code due to the CMS limitation).I will try to fix it with our development team

Comment: So Blexy I finally got back to this and found out that the issue is related to having the tracker object ready. I setup an event that is triggered once "event" equals to "gtm.load" and the value is passed on correctly. Thanks for the input once more :)

Comment: Ah, sounds like a race condition - macro was running prior to ga was loaded. Makes sense. Thanks for the follow up - this is good to know!

Comment: Also, I used this in combination with Simo's advice how to fire the tag just once per session (http://www.simoahava.com/analytic/universal-analytics-fire-script-just-per-session/) and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that GTM (Google Tag Manager) creates an object that is NOT called ga (it creates an object named ga followed by a random number), that's why 'ga' is not defined. You should try something on the lines of using the tag manager to put that client id into a javascript variable so you can access it from the page)

Comment: Please post more details

Comment: I haven't done that, but once I had a similar issue and had to put a mixed solution (using GTM and UA code for cross domain tracking). I know it could be done entirely (or mostly) using GTM but time was an issue. 

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I was reading up on setting client ids and came across this blog link about accessing client ID in GA while using Google Tag Manager. Might be helpful.

[Accessing Client ID in GA using custom dimensions](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/improve-data-collection-with-four-custom-dimensions/)