# New users vs active users in Measurement protocol

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

How does google analytics measure active users vs. new users in measurement protocol .

How does it measure new users? , Is it based on ipaddress ? I send the same cid=555 for all requests.

In website I see that it uses cookies though

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CID actually stands for *client-id*](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains#getClientId) = random number generated by Google Analytics when you come to a website for the first time. You can easily [grab it (even with GTM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976976/accessing-clientid-set-by-google-analytics-through-google-tag-manager) and use it with Measurement Protocol.

If you use client-id that GA can recognize, it will stitch the data together (campaign source/medium) etc. If you use a new one (like '555' you mentioned), it will then see the incoming measurement protocol request as a request from new user.

**Be smart though what you use as CID -- it the key that's vital to pairing any information you might already have about your visitors.**

Comment: So If I need to capture returning users / new users , i should be using the user id parameter ( Example - Hash a user name and map to a user id ) so that we can accurately determine if the user is a returning user or a new user .

Comment: is there a way how you can record CID generated by GA?

Comment: My app is a desktop application and not hosted on web. Thus need to use only measurement protocol and the http request constructs expects cid as a required parameter. Thus cid should be generated by the applicatoin itself as a unique id (UUID ), but I think to find out active vs. returning users it needs to be based on user id parameter ( which maps to unique username ) and not on cid ??

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure in this case. If you use your own IDs, then I would make sure you are using consistent ones for the same user - but I haven't validate this...

Comment: user id is for something else - stitching visits coming from the same users but different devices (and MP requires use of CID in all requests, USER ID then works as additional key, not the primary one!)

Comment: I am using the user id field to tie information for each unique user to my application. I created a new view for it , but not sure how to tell the view to base its data using User Id. In short , how to view profiles per User Id parameter . Thank you

Comment: The only article I know is providing some context is this one: http://cutroni.com/blog/2014/04/10/understanding-cross-device-measurement-and-the-user-id/

Comment: This hit does not seem to get registered in user id view in real time tab -- http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?&ul=en-US&v=1&tid=UA-xxxxx-2&cid={9ddbf6d0-1909-4ea8-afd0-bcbfbbfd1c3e}&t=pageview&dt=Stest%20tab&dp=test%20tab&uid=hsjfy4782jduyth6k4