# Why is UserID reported as anonymous data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have setup google analytics userID extensions, according to the [guide](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666), here is my code:

```
ga('create', 'UA-10303525-4', { 'userId': current.user.longid });
ga('send', 'pageview', '/purchase/invoicing');
```

After three days, all logged in user data is still reported as anonymous data and not shown in the userID registered profile. What could cause this and is there any way to debug UserId, like seiing if a userID is set?

Here is my http-get(the uid-parameter is correct):

```
:host:www.google-analytics.com
:method:GET
:path:/collect?v=1&_v=j22&a=1163329869&t=%2Fhome&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.zenconomy.se%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Hem%20-%20Zenconomy&sd=24-bit&sr=1280x800&vp=1152x702&je=1&fl=14.0%20r0&_utma=114769036.1265230233.1399066225.1403176480.1403201211.129&_utmz=114769036.1403201211.129.40.utmcsr%3Dfeedly.com%7Cutmccn%3D(referral)%7Cutmcmd%3Dreferral%7Cutmcct%3D%2F&_utmht=1403465598782&_u=MACCAAQ~&cid=1265230233.1399066225&uid=4fe4eb106f185&tid=UA-10303525-4&z=695256044
:scheme:https
:version:HTTP/1.1
accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,es;q=0.2,nb;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2
cache-control:no-cache
pragma:no-cache
referer:https://www.zenconomy.se/
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
v:1
_v:j22
a:1163329869
t:/home
_s:1
dl:https://www.zenconomy.se/
ul:en-us
de:UTF-8
dt:Hem - Zenconomy
sd:24-bit
sr:1280x800
vp:1152x702
je:1
fl:14.0 r0
_utma:114769036.1265230233.1399066225.1403176480.1403201211.129
_utmz:114769036.1403201211.129.40.utmcsr=feedly.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/
_utmht:1403465598782
_u:MACCAAQ~
cid:1265230233.1399066225
uid:4fe4eb106f185
tid:UA-10303525-4
z:695256044
Response Headers
access-control-allow-origin:*
age:242993
alternate-protocol:443:quic
cache-control:private, no-cache, no-cache=Set-Cookie, proxy-revalidate
content-length:35
content-type:image/gif
date:Fri, 20 Jun 2014 00:03:25 GMT
expires:Mon, 07 Aug 1995 23:30:00 GMT
last-modified:Sun, 17 May 1998 03:00:00 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server:Golfe2
status:200 OK
version:HTTP/1.1
x-content-type-options:nosniff
```

Answer (score 0):

Kristoffer, I think this is on purpose, given UserID is not mentioned in [Dimension/Metric Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) either.

What you can easily do is to set UserID (or cliend ID) as a CustomDimension. This can be done easily even with [Google Tag Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976976/accessing-clientid-set-by-google-analytics-through-google-tag-manager).

Hope this helps!